# Bloomberg SAPI authentication

Tags: bloomberg

I am trying to use the BLPAPI to establish a connection to SAPI. I am unclear on how to pass the authentication to SAPI. For instance, how do I specify the SAPI server(some url?) or how do I pass the authentication( public/private keys) over for the connection to be established?